# Lucene 4.x - read filename/unique ID fields from each doc in index

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, filenames

I have a series of documents that I'm indexing with Lucene, and as far as I know the index is being created correctly. I want to store the filename string in the index for each document and then later read that filename field from the index when I pull a similarity score so I can tell which doc is which. Unfortunately, nothing I've tried has worked so far, either because it's for a different version of Lucene, or (maybe?) because it doesn't work with the way I've set up my fields/docs.

My filename field is being stored like this:

```
    for (File f : sourceDirectory.listFiles()) {
        ...
        FieldType docFNfieldType = new FieldType();
        docFNfieldType.setIndexed(true);
        docFNfieldType.setStored(true);
        docFNfieldType.setStoreTermVectors(false);
        docFNfieldType.setTokenized(false);
        String docfilename = f.getName(); 
        Field docFN = new Field("filename", docfilename, docFNfieldType);
        doc.add(docFN);
        ...
```

I've alternately tried each of the following methods (not listing all code for each since otherwise it would be too much for one post):

```
* String[] allIDs = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getTerms()  //with (int docNum / indexReader, string field)
* String[] allIDs = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getStrings()
* String the_filename = hitDoc.getFieldable("filename").stringValue();
* TermEnum te = indexSearcher.Terms(new Term("fieldx"));
* Terms idnum = indexReader.getTermVector(docId, "filename");  //only when setTermVector is true, but then returns gobbledegook, not the string of the filename
```

I have no idea what else I need to do or what else I can try, and I've already wasted a month on trying to fix this problem without any measurable change. Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you want the other lines of code for any of the sections above that I've tried. I'm just trying to keep this post somewhat clean and concise.